# why i'm getting "_debugSource" as "undefined" in FiberNode?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-fiber

My question is why I'm getting `_debugSource` as `undefined` in FiberNode?

```
import * as React from "react";

export default function SimplePopper() {
  const handleClick = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
    console.log(
      event.currentTarget[
        Object.keys(event.currentTarget).reduce((key) => {
          if (key.match(new RegExp("__reactFiber", "i"))) {
            return key;
          }
          return null;
        })
      ]
    );
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>
        button
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

In this code sample first I'm getting the DOM reference of the `Button` and then extracting `fiberNode` from that reference object

As you can see in this image, its `undefined` [image]

Answer (score 1):

apparently this happens when the source map is missing.